# (Flutter) Начал писать код по инструкции. Нужно переделать под Null Safety. Показывает ошибку setState. Помогите пожалуйста, как решить эти проблемы

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum GenderList { male, female }

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState();
}

class MyFormState extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late GenderList _gender;
  bool _agreement = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  'Имя пользователя:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                new TextFormField(validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Пожалуйста введите свое имя';
                }),
                new SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                new Text(
                  'Контактный E-mail:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                new TextFormField(validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Пожалуйста введите свой Email';

                  String p =
                      "[a-zA-Z0-9+.\_\%-+]{1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}(.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25})+";
                  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);

                  if (regExp.hasMatch(value)) return null;

                  return 'Это не E-mail';
                }),
                new SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                new Text(
                  'Ваш пол:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                new RadioListTile(
                  title: const Text('Мужской'),
                  value: GenderList.male,
                  groupValue: _gender,
                  onChanged: (GenderList value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _gender = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                new RadioListTile(
                  title: const Text('Женский'),
                  value: GenderList.female,
                  groupValue: _gender,
                  onChanged: (GenderList value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _gender = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                new SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                new CheckboxListTile(
                    value: _agreement,
                    title: new Text('Я ознакомлен' +
                        (_gender == null
                            ? '(а)'
                            : _gender == GenderList.male
                                ? ''
                                : 'а') +
                        ' с документом "Согласие на обработку персональных данных" и даю согласие на обработку моих персональных данных в соответствии с требованиями "Закона О персональных данных № 152-ФЗ".'),
                    onChanged: (bool value) =>
                        setState(() => _agreement = value)),
                new SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      Color color = Colors.red;
                      String text;

                      if (_gender == null)
                        text = 'Выберите свой пол';
                      else if (_agreement == false)
                        text = 'Необходимо принять условия соглашения';
                      else {
                        text = 'Форма успешно заполнена';
                        color = Colors.green;
                      }

                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text(text),
                        backgroundColor: color,
                      ));
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Проверить'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Flutter.su - Форма ввода')),
        body: new MyForm())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает информации о том, в каком месте выдает ошибку.
Может поможет если изменить:

```
late GenderList _gender;
```

На

```
late GenderList? _gender;
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, буду как-то пробовать

Answer (score 0):

```
late GenderList _gender;
```

В данной строке объявлена, но не инициализирована переменная.
Соответственно, если к ней произойдет обращение до того, как ей будет присвоено значение, вы столкнетесь с ошибкой.

Здесь есть 2 варианта выхода:

1. Инициализировать сразу

   GenderList _gender = GenderList.female;
2. Сделать ее нулабельной:

   GenderList? _gender;

Во втором случае нужно будет в дальнейшем добавить проверки на null:

```
groupValue: _gender ?? GenderList.female,
```

Comment: Попробовал эти варианты, но чего-то все равно не хочет, вот такую ошибку выдает: 
E/SurfaceSyncer( 6322): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 6322): Expecting binder but got null!

Comment: Скопировал ваш код в dartpad, чтоб проверить. Т.к. у вас устаревшая версия flutter, мне пришлось стилистически обновить код под flutter 3.3.8.

Получилось вот так: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=88ba21ad029c83ea79af306910c0c099

Запуск этого варианта к эксепшенам, как можно увидеть, не приводит.
Соответственно вы можете посмотреть, чем принципиально отличается мой вариант от вашего (в плане nullsafety) и у себя это воспроизвести. Если эксепшен останется, значит он связан не с этим кодом.

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, все работает. Там в 29 строчке я заменил на "true" и теперь работает так как надо, потому что когда стояло false, форма пропускала когда поле с именем пустое и выдавало ошибку когда имя введено. Реально спасибо большое за помощь!